# Toolkit Error: Stage Details Not Supported: VarHandleOp

Tags: tensorflow, keras, raspberry-pi, intel

I have trained a model using keras and saved to json file and `.h5` weight file. Then I need to put this run on intel Neural Compute stick. So I converted these two model and weight files to `.meta` file for tensorflow using my repo: 
https://github.com/anuragcp/to_ncs_graph.git

Prediction working without NCS. On creating graph from this meta file using mvNCCompile command it make an error:

```
[Error 5] Toolkit Error: Stage Details Not Supported: VarHandleOp
```

I Have checked on both ncsdk v1 & v2 - same result.

Any idea how to solve this?